# Madia-queries not working inside an iframe

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have an HTML page that contains an `iframe` element that takes up 100% of the width of the window. Within that `iframe`'s HTML and CSS, I am attempting to use media queries, but they don't seem to work.

I included the following in the `head` of the `iframe` markup:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

And tried using this in the `iframe` CSS file:

```
@media (max-device-width: 500px) {...}
```

or

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 500px) {...}
```

or

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {...}
```

If I try using this code in a normal page, without an `iframe`, it works fine.

Should media queries not work, even within an `iframe`?

Comment: What are you trying to target? The width of the browser or the width of the Iframe?

Comment: iframe is 100% width of the browser

Comment: So is your media queries in your .html or the iframe's .html

Comment: @HunterTurner this is not a DUP of the link you shared, OP I bet is having a totally different issue.

Comment: <main html><iframe><child html><link to css styling child html with media queries/></child html></iframe></main html>

Comment: that doesnt make sense add it here so we can see what you are seeing: https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1):

Ok I have two fiddles for you.

This has the I frame and the media queries:
https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/komfhjdj/11/

And this one has you `iframe`:
https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/ynk1k1hj/

Notice the background color changes when the viewport in the iframe get below `300px`

I don't know your specific question so I am giving you a broad answer, however, leave me a comment with any questions, and I will attempt answer them for you

Comment: Your code dosen't work - I'm opening it in mobile IE 11 - background doesn't changed

Comment: @p0mian What window are you re-sizing? the browser or the iframe?

Comment: Just tested in ie11, it works fine.

Comment: i'm opening it at mobile device - microsoft lumia - browser is smaller :)

Comment: maybe my mobile browser is fu*ked up

Comment: @p0mian No, I think it probably is just fine, what phone do you have and what color is the background right now? red or green?

Comment: background is red, lumia 535 edit: wait - is green after second refresh in second link :(

Comment: What color is it now? https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/ynk1k1hj/1/

Comment: now is green, but I don't now why is not working on my original site :(, maybe browser or some think on parent site

Comment: Are you testing only on your phone? or deskpot?

Comment: parent site is wordpress theme with blocked zoom, changing window size doesn't work too